# How to make the <li> items next to each other?

Tags: html, css

For hours, I've been trying to put the `li` lists next to each other, but still couldn't make it.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rsp3gsg3/

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
img {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
#menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
}
.ulinlineblock {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
    <img src="Header.png" />
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="ulinlineblock">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Wiki</li>
            <li>Trivia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `li { display: inline }`. You didn't style the `<li>` at all, just their containing `<ul>`.

Comment: tried that, but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Fixed it :) View my post

Comment: @JugglingBob, did my answer help you? It seems to have fixed your problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `li` to inline block.

```
.ulinlineblock {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.ulinlineblock li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsp3gsg3/4/

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
img {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
#menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
}
.ulinlineblock {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.ulinlineblock li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
    <img src="Header.png" />
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="ulinlineblock">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Wiki</li>
            <li>Trivia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```